# Babel transpilation reserved keyword 'package' error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, babeljs, mern

I'm working on a MERN stack app with Babel on the server side of things so that I can write ES6. I'm getting an error when I try to deploy to Heroku: "Unexpected reserved word 'package'"

My Heroku-related scripts:

```
{
  "build": "babel . -d build --ignore ./client,node_modules",
  "heroku-postbuild": "YARN_PRODUCTION=false yarn build && yarn --cwd client install && yarn --cwd client build"
}
```

Full error message:

```
remote: SyntaxError: /tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/init-package-json/default-input.js: Unexpected reserved word 'package' (48:11)
remote: 
remote:   46 | }}
remote:   47 | 
remote: > 48 | var name = package.name || basename
remote:      |            ^
remote:   49 | var spec
remote:   50 | try {
remote:   51 |   spec = npa(name)
remote:     at Object._raise (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:757:17)
remote:     at Object.raiseWithData (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:750:17)
remote:     at Object.raise (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:744:17)
remote:     at Object.checkReservedWord (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10916:14)
remote:     at Object.parseIdentifierName (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10876:12)
remote:     at Object.parseIdentifier (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10847:23)
remote:     at Object.parseExprAtom (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9958:27)
remote:     at Object.parseExprAtom (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4648:20)
remote:     at Object.parseExprSubscripts (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9688:23)
remote:     at Object.parseMaybeUnary (/tmp/build_92b72922d4bd2872f60dec7f1e038c5d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9668:21) {
remote:   loc: Position { line: 48, column: 11 },
remote:   pos: 1484,
remote:   code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
remote: }
```

Couple of things to note:

- I had to add `node_modules` to Babel ignore (I'm not sure whether this is a good idea though) because it was giving me an `Unexpected token` error:

  ```js
  import * as $protobuf from $DEPENDENCY;` // On the `$` of "$DEPENDENCY"
  ```
- I assumed I didn't want to transpile the client folder because React has its own build script (default one)
- My babel config:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
  };
  ```
- My folder structure:

  [image: folder structure]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a fix:

I just had to put every server related files/folder into its own directory and update the babel transpilation script as needed

Comment: Describe what "as needed" actually means